# Annotating Pandas Barplot with an Additional Value Unrelated to the Plot's x and y Axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am producing a pandas barplot with raw counts represented by the plot, however I would like to annotate the bars with the pct of those counts as a whole. I have seen a lot of people using `ax.patches` methods to annotate but my values are unrelated to the `get_height` of the actual bars.

Here is some toy data. The plot produced will be the individual counts of the specific type. However, I want to add annotations above that specific bar that represent the pct total of that specific type to all types for that person's name.

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


d = {'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4], 
     'name': ['bob','bob','bob','shelby','shelby','jordan','jordan','jordan','jeff'],
     'type': ['type1','type2','type4','type1','type6','type5','type8','type2',None]}
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_pivot: pd.DataFrame = df.pivot_table(index='type', columns=['name'], values='ID', aggfunc={'ID': np.sum}).fillna(0)

# create percent totals of the specific type's row of the total
df_pivot['bob_pct_total']: pd.Series = (df_pivot['bob']/df_pivot['bob'].sum()).mul(100).round(1)
df_pivot['shelby_pct_total']: pd.Series = (df_pivot['shelby']/df_pivot['shelby'].sum()).mul(100).round(1)
df_pivot['jordan_pct_total']: pd.Series = (df_pivot['jordan']/df_pivot['jordan'].sum()).mul(100).round(1)
df_pivot.head(10)

name    bob jordan  shelby  bob_pct_total   shelby_pct_total    jordan_pct_total
type                        
type1   1.0   0.0      2.0           33.3               50.0                0.0
type2   1.0   3.0      0.0           33.3                0.0               33.3
type4   1.0   0.0      0.0           33.3                0.0                0.0
type5   0.0   3.0      0.0            0.0                0.0               33.3
type6   0.0   0.0      2.0            0.0               50.0                0.0
type8   0.0   3.0      0.0            0.0                0.0               33.3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
df_pivot.plot(kind='bar', y=['bob','jordan','shelby'], ax=ax)
```

Comment: You can use `get_height()` to calculate the position and then write another whatever other string there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the old approach, looping through the bars, using the height to position whatever text you want.  Since matplotlib 3.4.0 there also is a new function [`bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) that removes much of the boilerplate:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
     'name': ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'shelby', 'shelby', 'jordan', 'jordan', 'jordan', 'jeff'],
     'type': ['type1', 'type2', 'type4', 'type1', 'type6', 'type5', 'type8', 'type2', None]}
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_pivot: pd.DataFrame = df.pivot_table(index='type', columns=['name'], values='ID', aggfunc={'ID': np.sum}).fillna(0)

# create percent totals of the specific type's row of the total
df_pivot['bob_pct_total']: pd.Series = (df_pivot['bob'] / df_pivot['bob'].sum()).mul(100).round(1)
df_pivot['shelby_pct_total']: pd.Series = (df_pivot['shelby'] / df_pivot['shelby'].sum()).mul(100).round(1)
df_pivot['jordan_pct_total']: pd.Series = (df_pivot['jordan'] / df_pivot['jordan'].sum()).mul(100).round(1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
columns = ['bob', 'jordan', 'shelby']
df_pivot.plot(kind='bar', y=['bob', 'jordan', 'shelby'], rot=0, ax=ax)
for bars, col in zip(ax.containers, ['bob_pct_total', 'jordan_pct_total', 'shelby_pct_total']):
    ax.bar_label(bars, labels=['' if val == 0 else f'{val}' for val in df_pivot[col]])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: bar_label on pandas barplot]

PS: To skip labeling the first bars, you could experiment with:

```py
for bars, col in zip(ax.containers, ['bob_pct_total', 'jordan_pct_total', 'shelby_pct_total']):
    labels=['' if val == 0 else f'{val}' for val in df_pivot[col]]
    labels[0] = ''
    ax.bar_label(bars, labels=labels)
```

Comment: This is really good. I was using an older version of Matplotlib. Just updated and this really helps. I always found annotation in Matplotlib to be really cumbersome and frustrating but this is perfect!

Comment: This might be a bit niche, but if I wanted to omit one of the bar group's annotations, how could I do that? Since containers contains 6 artists, I would need to omit the first artist for each container. So basically if I wanted 'type1' annotations to be hidden, how could I proceed? I suppose I could just manually set those vals to 0 so that when it plots it just makes them blank.

Comment: Yes, it probably is easiest just setting that value to zero.